# how to use jquery ui only datepicker with datemonth?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jquery ui datepicker but I'm not using another components of jquery ui (tab,accordion,autocomplete and other..) just datepicker that's why I choose custom download..everything is okey my datepicker is work very well but my month picker is not working I'm [Monthpicker plugin](https://github.com/KidSysco/jquery-ui-month-picker) for month my plugin give me a error but if I'm using full jquery ui with all components my monthPicker is working but I have to use only with datepicker

[please click to see my demo](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/xqdeWQ)

[image]

```
<div class="example">
  <h1>This is example datepicker</h1>
 <input type="text"  placeholder="Chekin" id="checkin">
</div>

<div class="project">
  <h1>And this is the project monthPicker</h1>
  <input type="text" id="noIconDemo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the alert that you need both Button and Datepicker, and you say you only have Datepicker. You should try downloading a custom build with both plugins.

https://jqueryui.com/download/#!version=1.12.1&components=100001011000000000011110000000000000000000000000